# returning all email addresses of a certain type from a .csv file in python

Tags: python, regex

I've been working on this piece of code in python all morning and I can't get it to return the results I'm looking for.  I have a .csv file containing some mock customer information to include email addresses.  I want to return a list of email addresses that are .edu

Heres what I have (I'm a Python novice and actually am really trying to learn Kotlin, not python) Also, there may be a better way than using regex, but Im trying to accomplish it this way.  IF there is a better way, I'm open to suggestions as to what and why.

```
import csv
import re

data = []

with open('customerdata.csv') as f:
  reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=',')
  for row in reader:
    data.append(row[7])
str1 = ' '.join(data)

edupattern = r'\b(.edu)'

regex = re.compile(edupattern, re.IGNORECASE)
for match in regex.findall(str1):
    print(match)
```

The problem is that it only prints .edu however many times it appears in the .csv file.  Why am I not getting the entire email addresses printing out?

Comment: Your problem is joining it all together into a single string. Just filter `data`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import csv
import re

data = []

with open('customerdata.csv') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=',')
    for row in reader:
        if re.search(r'\.edu\b', row[7]): # you could also use row[7].endswith('.edu')
            data.append(row[7])

print(' '.join(data))
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your regex should be:

```
= r"\b(\S+\.edu)"
```

When you use a capture group, You only get the capture(i.e., the `.edu` part). You should also include all non- `S`pace characters inside the capture.